# How to get type from String?

Tags: java, string, class, types

To be specific - I don't even know if it's possible, but there may be something, that I'm missing.
I need to get class type from String and use it as a generic type:

```
//Don't mind this
String columnName = n.getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getTextContent(); 

//That would be canonical class name    
String columnType = n.getAttributes().getNamedItem("type").getTextContent();

Column<**Type from columnName**> col = new Column<>(columnName);
```

Is something like that even possible?

Comment: No, it is not. Generics are a compile time concept. They don't exist at run time.

Comment: It's possible to get a `Class` from a string name, but that won't help you here.  Generic parameters are a *compile-time* thing; you have information that's only known at *run-time*.

Comment: you might wanna consider writing separate parameterized classes for both columnName and columnType.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know exactly what you mean.

But to get a Type from a String you have to use

```
Class clazz = Class.forName("YourString");
```

If the classloader is able to resolve you given String to a class which is located within
the classpath it will provide you an instance of type Class.

With the expression

```
Object obj = clazz.newInstance();
```

you can create an instance of this type.

I think there exists some kind of expression like this

```
ArrayList<? super Double> list;
```

and in your case:

```
Column<? super GenericColumn> col = new Column<GenericColumn>(columnName);
```

This means your class given by the appropriate String must inherit from 
a GenericColumn which is already known during runtime. Maybe this could be a solution for you problem.

Anyway In this case i think that generics are not usefull.

Comment: Actually, I forgot to say, that Column parameter holds data type used in it. Column<T> was meant to be used like Vector<T> or List<T>.

Comment: Yeah actually i think i knew what you meant. So in any case i and like the comments beneath your question already mentioned there is no typesafe way doin what you want. You always must fallback to a abstract or interface class to be able to declare the column as a generic type. But it is a really interssting problem.